# Why does a return in `finally` override `return` value in `try` block?

Tags: javascript, return, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

How does a return statement inside a try/catch block work?

```
function example() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    finally {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output of this function to be `true`, but instead it is `false`!

Comment: For others, do the return false in the catch block, not finally.

Comment: Use finally not for logic but for clean-up, eg to free resources.  A return statement is not appropriate for use in finally.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Finally *always* executes. That's what it's for, which means its return value gets used in your case.

You'll want to change your code so it's more like this:

```
function example() { 
    var returnState = false; // initialization value is really up to the design
    try { 
        returnState = true; 
    } 
    catch {
        returnState = false;
    }
    finally { 
        return returnState; 
    } 
}
```

Generally speaking you never want to have more than one return statement in a function, things like this are why.

Comment: I would argue having more than one return statement isn't always bad - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement for more discussion.

Comment: I too disagree about the one return rule. You should never return from finally, though (in C#, it's not even allowed).

Comment: @erikkallen - that's a good point. A return outside the T-C-F block would be best but the example code would be a bit forced :)

Comment: @Castrohenge - it's not a hard and fast rule, but most of the copunter-examples in that thread are pretty contrived, and the only valid case I see is the "guard clause" (essentially the pattern of checking input data at the top of the function and returning conditionally). That's a perfectly valid case, but really those returns should be exceptions (again not hard and fast).

Comment: Actually in IE6 and IE7, finally doesn't always execute in all cases due to a pretty serious browser bug. Specifically – if an exception is thrown in a try-finally block that isn't surrounded by a higher level try-catch, then the finally block won't execute. Here's a test case http://jsfiddle.net/niallsmart/aFjKq/. This issue was fixed in IE8.

Comment: To always have at most one return statement per function is a [misinterpreted historical advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793/309002) and is generally [agreed to be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement).

Comment: It's [unsafe](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unsafe-finally) to `return` from `finally`.

Answer (score 69):

According to ECMA-262 (5ed, December 2009), in pp. 96:

> The production `TryStatement : try Block Finally` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let B be the result of evaluating Block.
> 2. Let F be the result of evaluating Finally.
> 3. If F.type is normal, return B.
> 4. Return F.

And from pp. 36:

> The Completion type is used to explain the behaviour of statements (`break`, `continue`, `return` and `throw`) that perform nonlocal transfers of control. Values of the Completion type are triples of the form *(type, value, target)*, where *type* is one of `normal`, `break`, `continue`, `return`, or `throw`, *value* is any ECMAScript language value or empty, and *target* is any ECMAScript identifier or empty.

It's clear that `return false` would set completion type of *finally* as *return*, which cause `try ... finally` to do *4. Return F*.

Comment: After reading all sorts of "basically correct but somehow squishy and non-clarifying" answers to this question, this one actually made it make sense. The key bit was that whatever "happens" at the end of the try+catch (return or throw or just normal flow) is _remembered_ while it runs the finally part and then actually happens only if nothing happens at the end of finally.

Answer (score 24):

When you use `finally`, any code within that block fires before the method exits. Because you're using a return in the `finally` block, it calls `return false` and overrides the previous `return true` in the `try` block.

(Terminology might not be quite right.)

Answer (score 12):

The finally block rewrites try block return (figuratively speaking).

Just wanted to point out, that if you return something from finally, then it will be returned from the function. But if in finally there is no 'return' word - it will be returned the value from try block;

```js
function example() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    finally {
       console.log('finally')
    }
}
console.log(example());
// -> finally
// -> true
```

So -finally- `return` rewrites the return of -try- `return`.

Answer (score 8):

I'm gonna give a slightly different answer here: Yes, both the `try` and `finally` block get executed, and `finally` takes precedence over the actual "return" value for a function. However, these return values aren't always used in your code.

Here's why:

- The example below will use `res.send()` from Express.js, which creates a HTTP response and dispatches it.
- Your `try` and `finally` block will both execute this function like so:

```js
try {
    // Get DB records etc.
    return res.send('try');
} catch(e) {
    // log errors
} finally {
    return res.send('finally');
}
```

This code will show the string `try` in your browser. ALSO, the example will show an error in your console. The `res.send()` function is called *twice*. This will happen with anything that is a function. The try-catch-finally block will obfuscate this fact to the untrained eye, because (personally) I only associate `return` values with function-scopes.

Imho your best bet is to **never use `return` inside a `finally` block**. It will overcomplicate your code and potentially mask errors.

In fact, there's a default code inspection rule set-up in PHPStorm that gives a "Warning" for this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/javascript-and-typescript-return-inside-finally-block.html

#### So what do you use `finally` for?

I would use `finally` only to clean-up stuff. Anything that is not critical for the return value of a function.

It may make sense if you think about it, because when you depend on a line of code under `finally`, you are assuming that there could be errors in `try` or `catch`. But those last 2 are the actual building blocks of error handling. Just use a `return` in `try` and `catch` instead.

Comment: Strongly agree with this answer - would only add that if your running into issues with the return behavior, just put the return outside the finally block!  It always runs there unless you return in the try/catch!

I think it would be better to have another language construct for finally outside the try/catch behavior because of this oddity though, something like do {/*stuff*/} always {/*clean up*/)

Answer (score 3):

why you are getting false is you returned in a finally block. finally block should execute always. so your `return true` changes to `return false`

```
function example() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Returning from a finally-block**
>
> If the `finally`-block returns a value, this value becomes the return
>   value of the entire `try-catch-finally` statement, regardless of any
>   `return` statements in the `try` and `catch`-blocks

Reference: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `finally` block **always** executes, irrespective of whether you have a `return` statement inside `try` or not. Ergo, you get the value returned by the `return` statement inside finally block.

I tested this with Firefox 3.6.10 and Chrome 6.0.472.63 both in Ubuntu. It is possible that this code may behave differently in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should remember in *try/catch/finally* is that the '**The last return always wins**'.
You can not skip the *finally* block with the return statement inside *try* or *catch* block. It will always be executed at the end.
There is a nice [post](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/last-return-wins/) about that. Hope it can help you to understand better.

Answer (score -2):

Finally is supposed to ALWAYS run at the end of a try catch block so that (by specification) is why you are getting false returned. Keep in mind that it is entirely possible that different browsers have different implementations.

Comment: IE8, Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 6: all the same ;)