# Will the code in finally be run if I have program flow like this?

Tags: php

I was wondering if the following program flow will prevent the finally from being run in this try-catch-finally block due to a return in the try.

Please excuse poor error checking and sanitisation, this is just a mock:

```
function doLogin() {

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', "root", "");
    $errors = array();
    $loginSuccess = false;

    try {
        $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *
                                FROM users
                                WHERE username = :username');
        $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])) {
            array_push($errors, 'Invalid password.');
            return; // will this return prevent the finally from being run?
        }
        else {
            $loginSuccess = true;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $pdoEx) {
        echo 'Error occurred ' . $pdoEx->getMessage();
    }
    finally {
        $dbh = null;
    }

}
```

Code is pretty poorly written, but hopefully you understand my point.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837994/javascript-try-catch-return-statement

Comment: Why not write a quick example program to test it?

Comment: @VinceEmigh - That question is regarding Javascript.  Although PHP and Javascript have some similarities, they're absolutely not the same language and may handle things differently.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I'll get to doing that, just wanted to quickly pop in and ask SO just in case it was very basic program flow knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, the code in finally will be run.

For example:

```
function example() {
    try {
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "error";    
    }
    finally{
        return false;
    }
}
var_dump( example() );
```

Outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

It's also (hiddenly) stated in the docs:

> In PHP 5.5 and later, a finally block may also be specified after the
>   catch blocks. Code within the finally block will always be executed
>   after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an exception has
>   been thrown, and **before normal execution** resumes.

To my understanding the try block finishes with the `return` statement. The *normal execution* is "paused" and the finally executed.

Comment: Thanks, and yep just did a quick test myself (which I should have done from the beginning) [here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc5a8020df2a3b2447f7c16bda3f5062d4320b99)